# May I shrink SharePoint 2019 Content database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

As I mentioned in my previous question that my SharePoint content database is almost full, deleting version didn't free up any space. May I shrink the Content database(not log file) , right clicking the database, if yes, is there any consequence ?
Thank you very much.

Sincerely

Farook Golam

Comment: I think you should do some more research about database-management for SharePoint. When you say that your database are almost full - at what size? Databases in SharePoint do grow based on your configuration when needed, like other SQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can shrink SharePoint Content database Data file. DBCC SHRINKDATABASE shrinks the data and log files for a specific database. To shrink individual files, use DBCC SHRINKFILE. To shrink a database by using SQL Server 2019 Management Studio, expand Databases, right-click the database that you want to shrink, choose Tasks, Shrink, Files.

[image]

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.